# Transport-level error has occurred after SET MULTI_USER

Tags: c#, sql

Today we got the "Transport-level error has occurred" error of death happening in one of our customer's slow and low ram computer while running one of the most critical processes of our application.

Looking at the SQL log file I saw that SET MULTI_USER was the last successful statement before the error.

When I looked at the code I could see that we run multiple scripts and then we change the DB to single user mode to run more scripts, and then we put it back to Multi User mode. Something like:

```
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012 SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
-- Critical Operation
GO
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012 SET MULTI_USER;
```

After this script we would call the DB with other scripts to select tables or do other stuff, but the next scripts failed with the "Transport-level error has occurred"

**What would be the best way to avoid the error after this query?**

Comment: are you saying the single user was set by sql itself with no user intervention?

Comment: No, we set it to Single_User to make sure no one uses the system while we run some critical operations.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that calling the following code right after the script solved the problem.

```
SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
```

I'm not sure why this only happened in 1 out 100 customers, but this solved the problem. 
[ClearAllPools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearallpools.aspx) resets (or empties) the connection pool

Comment: I wanted to post this question & answer since is a very specific case and very specific answer to a problem. When I saw other similar questions they weren't as specific as my problem. Now I know what to do if I see the "Transport-Level" error after Set Multi_User